# Extract values from nested object in plsql using Apex

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have this employee object and I need to store every value into variables.
I am wondering if it is an easy or smart way to get the values from nested objects.

I know I can get the values in this way:

```
v_first_name := APEX_JSON.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employee.firstName')
```

but how can I retrieve the values from address object or from options object?

Apex version 20.1.

```
{
   "employee":{
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Smith",
      "email":"jsmith@test.com",
      "phoneNumber":"‎(907) 247-8888",
      "address":{
         "street":"1527 Pond Reef Rd",
         "city":"Ketchikan",
         "state":"ALaska",
         "stateShort":"AK",
         "zipCode":99901,
         "country":"USA"
      },
      "categories":[
         {
            "categoryID":1,
            "categoryName":"Example1",
            "options":{
               "ind_1":1,
               "ind_2":0,
               "ind_3":0
            }
         },
         {
            "categoryID":2,
            "categoryName":"Example",
            "options":{
               "ind_1":1,
               "ind_2":1,
               "ind_3":1
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

address is just a nested json object so you can use the "dot" notation. categories is an array so you need to loop through the individual elements. Here is an example.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_json_text VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_count     PLS_INTEGER;
  l_members   WWV_FLOW_T_VARCHAR2;
  l_paths     APEX_T_VARCHAR2;
  l_exists    BOOLEAN;
  l_json_values    apex_json.t_values;

BEGIN 
l_json_text := '
{
   "employee":{
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Smith",
      "email":"jsmith@test.com",
      "phoneNumber":"‎(907) 247-8888",
      "address":{
         "street":"1527 Pond Reef Rd",
         "city":"Ketchikan",
         "state":"ALaska",
         "stateShort":"AK",
         "zipCode":99901,
         "country":"USA"
      },
      "categories":[
         {
            "categoryID":1,
            "categoryName":"Example1",
            "options":{
               "ind_1":1,
               "ind_2":0,
               "ind_3":0
            }
         },
         {
            "categoryID":2,
            "categoryName":"Example",
            "options":{
               "ind_1":1,
               "ind_2":1,
               "ind_3":1
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
';

  apex_json.parse(
    p_values => l_json_values,
    p_source => l_json_text
  );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('----------------------------------------'); 
    if apex_json.does_exist(p_path => 'employee.address.street',p_values => l_json_values) then 
      dbms_output.put_line('address: '||apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employee.address.street', p_values => l_json_values));
    end if; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('----------------------------------------'); 


  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('----------------------------------------'); 
    if apex_json.does_exist(p_path => 'employee.categories',p_values => l_json_values) then 
      dbms_output.put_line(APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'employee.categories', p_values => l_json_values) || ' Categories found'); 
      FOR r IN 1 .. APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'employee.categories', p_values => l_json_values) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('categoryName: '||apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employee.categories[%d].categoryName', p0 => r, p_values => l_json_values));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('options.ind_1: '||apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'employee.categories[%d].options.ind_1', p0 => r, p_values => l_json_values));
      END LOOP;
    end if; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('----------------------------------------'); 
END;
/


----------------------------------------
address: 1527 Pond Reef Rd
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
2 Categories found
categoryName: Example1
options.ind_1: 1
categoryName: Example
options.ind_1: 1
----------------------------------------


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```